overwritten first 512GB of 6TB HDD, how to recover from backup GPT and NTFS MFT Mirror?
I accidentally overwrote the first 512GB of a 6TB Hard Disk Drive (Western Digital "spinning rust"), due to choosing an incorrect target when cloning an SSD in Samsung Magician. The disk had been originally partitioned using GPT (Global Partition Table) as a single partition / volume / drive letter (i.e. one drive letter mapping to the entire available storage).
I have backups but some of the newest files were not on the backup yet. I have an inventory of the file names that were scheduled for backup. I'd like to recover some of these later files, which are probably near the end of the disk (the disk was almost full).
I'm aware of tools like TestDisk, EaseUs/GetFilesBack, etc. However, if possible, I'd like to take a methodical approach that does not rely on any "magic" of these tools, or payment. I'm ok with potentially having to modify TestDisk to accomplish this.
As I understand it, there should be a Backup GPT at the end of the disk, and an NTFS MFT Mirror "somewhere" on the disk.
What is the quickest way to recover files in this scenario? The tools I've tried so far insist on doing a full scan and some kind of heuristic "guessing", which seems wasteful when I already know I want to use the Backup GPT.

TestDisk your best hope to restore the backup GPT information

... but don't keep your hopes high.

Backup GPT information is almost certainly not required, it’s easy to recreate a single volume.

Ramhound, the backup GPT header does not really help when the MFT is (partly) overwritten. In this case, you can use the free and open source software Photorec as possible last line of defense against data loss.

Alex R, I modified your question.  There is just one partition table on a single disk. If that is GPT type, there is a backup as well. The term "drive" is not well defined. Drives sometimes have "drive letters" and we then know that they are not meant to be disks, but partitions or volumes.

@r2d3 the "drive" is a Western Digital Hard Disk Drive (HDD). I made some updates to try to make that clearer.

@AlexR - Please let the experts clarify your question, having a clear question, helps the entire community. Revision 3 was significantly better compared to the current revision

"I'd like to recover some of these later files, which are probably near the end of the disk (the disk was almost full)." - that's not how modern filesystems work and quite likely an incorrect presumption...


What is the quickest way to recover files in this scenario? The tools I've tried so far insist on doing a full scan and some kind of heuristic "guessing", which seems wasteful when I already know I want

You have most likely completely overwritten your MFT.
But the smaller your files were the more likely your MFT had been extended, hopefully into an area not affected by your failure.
In such a case a commercial recovery program could rescue the remains.
Otherwise "heuristic guessing" is the only strategy that is left over.
